# Angularjs freezes in loop suing $timeout to call function multiple times sequential after or less than a second?

Tags: angularjs

I want to be able to call a function repeatedly every second (or faster).
Assuming "startdate" contains the starting date in the text... In my controller:

```
scope.arrayoftimes=[{time:XXXX},{time:XXXXXX}]
scope.startdate = $('#startingdate'); //start date comes from text in an element
scope.speed = 1000;
scope.index = 0;

scope.timer = $timeout(scope.doSomething(), scope.speed);

scope.doSomething = function() {
    var currentTime = scope.startDate.html();
    for (var i=scope.index; i < scope.arrayoftimes.length; i++) {
         if(currentTime == roundTo(scope.arrayoftimes[i].time)) {
               $rootScope.$emit('timeMatch', scope.index);
               scope.index++;
               break;
         }
    }

    $timeout(scope.doSomething(), scope.speed);

}
```

The above code frezes my browser on execution. HOWEVER if I stick in an "alert" anywhere after the scope.index++ or inside the if condition, then it works fine (as long as I check "Prevent opening multiple dialog boxes")

```
scope.arrayoftimes=[{time:XXXX},{time:XXXXXX}]
scope.startdate = "//Insert Starting Date Here"
scope.speed = 1000;
scope.index = 0;

scope.timer = $timeout(scope.doSomething(), scope.speed);

scope.doSomething = function() {
    var currentTime = scope.startDate;
    for (var i=scope.index; i < scope.arrayoftimes.length; i++) {
         if(currentTime == roundTo(scope.arrayoftimes[i].time)) {
               $rootScope.$emit('timeMatch', scope.index);
               scope.index++;
               alert("alert"); // the existence of this alert message and checking prevent from opening more dialog boxes in chrome allows this to execute fine without freezing
               break;
         }
    }

    $timeout(scope.doSomething(), scope.speed);

}
```

What is going on? How can I get around this? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timeout call probably needs to be:

```
$timeout(function() { scope.doSomething(); }, scope.speed);
```

or

```
$timeout(scope.doSomething, scope.speed);
```

Otherwise you're executing doSomething() immediately which causes an infinite loop.

Comment: I think you might be onto something, but then I get "TypeError: undefined is not a function" for the line: var currentTime = scope.startDate;

Comment: That would be a strange error since you're not invoking a function with this line.

Comment: Updated question scope.startdate = $('#startingdate'); is what is causing the undefined.

Comment: Is that a jQuery call? You probably don't want to mix jQuery and Angular. They don't play well together.